# Read a number in a word from a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file called `guidefs.h` where it has the information about the versions of the project code.

It has `#define VERSION_MAJOR 2` & `#define VERSION_MINOR 1` in between the lines and I want to search these words and get the numbers 2 and 1 to variables MAJOR and MINOR respectively.

I did an extensive search but ended up in searching the words.Please let me know how can I search for these word and get the numbers associated with it.

Comment: And what did you try? This seems like a case for RE http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
import re

number_regex = r'#define\s+VERSION_M[AJIN]+OR\s+(\d+)'

with open("guidefs.h") as f:
    your_text = f.read()
    all_numbers = re.findall(number_regex, your_text)
    # This will return ['2', '1']
```

This will work for both your MAJOR and your MINOR numbers.

If you want a list of integers rather than a list of strings you can use a list comprehension by adding the following line:

```
all_numbers = [int(x) for x in all_numbers]
# This will return [2, 1]
```

Comment: I've not given full solution on purpose ;)

Comment: It's returning just an empty list!!

Comment: The regular expression works fine so I would check the content that is being read from the file. Put in a couple of print statements (e.g. `print(your_text)`) and check that it is reading the file correctly. You may also need to open your file as a [binary file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) by changing the open to `with open("guidefs.h", "rb") as f:`...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) this will do the trick.

eg: `re.findall(r'#define VERSION_MAJOR (\d+)', text)`

Take a look to [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) function

Comment: what is the argument'text'??

Comment: that is variable that should contain textual contents of file in which you're looking for text

Answer (score 1):

I did something like below and it worked for me.Thanks a lot for all the answers.

```
with open("path\to\guidefs.h") as f:
        text=f.read()
        versions=re.findall(r'#define\s+VERSION_M[AJIN]+OR\s+(\d+)',text)
        major_version=versions[0]
        minor_version=versions[1]
print major_version
print minor_version
```

Output:
2
1